# PHP CURL Couldn't connect to server

Tags: php, json, api, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to connect to a API with PHP7 CURL that return JSON data.
It's about the following URL's:

- http://api.infcache.com/get.php?format=json&itemnumber=all
- http://api.infcache.com/get.php?format=json&itemnumber=10550 (foreach item)

With the following PHP Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.infcache.com/get.php?format=json&itemnumber=all');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

$products = curl_exec($ch);

if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}

curl_close($ch);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($products);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I PING on the host in my Ubuntu Terminal on api.infcache.com it works.

I can also get the complete curl with the terminal:
curl -X GET 'http://api.infcache.com/get.php?fl&itemnumber=all'
The above returns all json but not in my php script

If I change the url in my curl to google.com there is full response. What is the issue with: api.infcache.com? And I already tried file_get_contents().

Can somebody tell me what to do next?

The error:

```
cURL error (7): Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: your code works for me, as is.  PHP5.6, osx. Could be a `networking` issue, (ie your firewall blocks outbound, or their inbound infrastructure blocks you inbound). Ping is not TCP/IP, some routing rules could allow ICMP, but block TCP .

Comment: Thanks for the reaction on my post. I also contacted my webhoster for firewall approval. I also think that this is a networking issue. Next week they are going to check the firewall. When I know more I will update this post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was at my webhoster. They added the Ip-address to the whitelist. So when you have this error with CURL. Just check your network setting or Firewall.